# Identify Which Item is the Non-Object (PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm relatively new to PHP and WordPress and this one error message "PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" has been plaguing me, and I'm sure there is an easy fix.  Can anybody scan the following code and let me know what could be the source of this error?  I'm confident I've narrowed it down to this block of code.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
// REDIRECT USERS IF THEY ARE IN THE WRONG SPOT
add_action ('template_redirect', 'bee_security');
function bee_security() {

    // set the page that people end up on if they try to access the wrong page
    $bee_redirecturl = '/private-page/home/';

    // get basic user information
    $bee_masteruserid = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'wpcf-user-masteruser', true);
    $bee_temppost = get_post($post = get_the_id());
    $bee_authorid = $bee_temppost->post_author;

    // determine if the current post type is related to households
    $bee_posttype_household = substr(get_post_type(), 0, 9);
    if ( $bee_posttype_household == "household") { 
        $bee_posttype_household = true; 
    } else { 
        $bee_posttype_household = false; 
    }

    // redirect the user if they are logged in and accessing the front page
    if ( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect($bee_redirecturl);
        exit;

    // redirect the user if they try to access somebody else's househould besides their own
    } elseif ( $bee_posttype_household == true ) {
        if ( $bee_authorid != get_current_user_id() && $bee_authorid != $bee_masteruserid ) {
          wp_redirect($bee_redirecturl);
          exit;
        } 
    // redirect the user if they try to make a review on someone else's behalf
    } elseif ( get_the_id() == 347 ) {
        $bee_childpost = get_post($_GET['childid']);
        $bee_childauthor = $bee_childpost->post_author;
        if ( $bee_childauthor != get_current_user_id() && $bee_childauthor != $bee_masteruserid ) {
            wp_redirect($bee_redirecturl); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error should give you the exact file and line number. No need to guess.

Comment: Php notices should give you the exact line the error occurs.

Comment: It did, but it was referencing another PHP file (not the snippet I'm editing via the plugin "Code Snippets").  Actually, I think I solved it.  It was the line with $bee_authorid = $bee_temppost->post_author;

Answer (score 0):

one of following values producing a error

```
$bee_authorid = $bee_temppost->post_author;
```

OR

```
$bee_childauthor = $bee_childpost->post_author;
```

`get_post()` not returning values, this is could be the reason

Comment: Thanks - I will look into that childauthor line as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured it out.  Of course, the minute I finally give up and ask for help, I figure it out!  I changed this line:

```
$bee_authorid = $bee_temppost->post_author;
```

To this:

```
$bee_authorid = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_id() );
```

I guess on some pages where a post might not be loading the line was returning null instead of as an object.